# How to correct rewrite rules in htaccess/mod_write

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite the following URLs:

```
/app/12345 => /app/vv_start.php?id=12345
/app/12345/login => /app/vv_login.php?id=12345
/app/12345/settings => /app/vv_settings.php?id=12345
```

I got so far:

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/login/?$                   app/vv_login.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/settings/?$                app/vv_settings.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/?$                         app/vv_start.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

The last rule causes a problem, because it seems to apply all the time. When I delete the last rule the first two rules work fine otherwise they do not. How can I correct the last rule?

By the way, is there a difference between those two rules and which one should I use (slash at the beginning of the URL)?

```
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/login/?$                   app/vv_login.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/login/?$                   /app/vv_login.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/login/?$   app/vv_login.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/settings/?$    app/vv_settings.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^app/([^/]+)/?$   app/vv_start.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

---

For your question on `/` before path: yes there is a difference because `/app` means you have a mount named of it(in terms of Linux/Unix) OR its a root/base location. Where without `/` means your `app` could be present like: `root/singh/htdocs` etc for an example. So yes, they both are having different meaning and purposes.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works fine, although I don't see the difference to my approach, which did not work. Do the ignore rules for files and directories make the difference? Why do we need them?

Comment: @Phantom, Glad that it worked for you. I have put conditions before each rule, to make sure if a url is not existing directory/folder AND non-existing file then execute this rule, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `.php` files are inside the `app/` subdirectory. You may use this code inside `app/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

# ignore rules for files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(login|setting)/?$ vv_$2.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ vv_start.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

You asked:

> By the way, is there a difference between those two rules and which one should I use (slash at the beginning of the url)?

I suggest not to use leading `/` for internal rewrite rules like this as your rewrite handler target is relative to current directory. It has an added advantage of preventing a rewrite loop in case rewrite handler target doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. My `.php-`files are not all inside the `app/` subdirectory, I just simplified my problem. Your solution looks pretty nice, but I think it is not suited for my problem. Could you please explain the first rule `RewriteRule ^ - [L]`?

Comment: It is for ignoring files and directories as mentioned in comment above the rule. This rule avoids writing same repeated RewriteCond  before each RewriteRule. I have also commented 2 of the rewrite rules into one using regex pattern with alternation